# How to save data jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some dynamic data in my  element. Look at the sample below:

```
<div id="chart_1"></div>
```

There are 75 questions that the user answers and then the average is taken, and it must be represented on a graph.

```
<ul class="clearfix">
 <li>
  <div class="container_numbers">
   <input type="radio" id="1" name="question_1" class="required media_1" value="1">
   <label class="radio very_bad" for="1">1</label>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <div class="container_numbers">
   <input type="radio" id="2" name="question_1" class="required media_1" value="2">
    <label class="radio bad" for="2">2</label>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <div class="container_numbers">
   <input type="radio" id="3" name="question_1" class="required media_1" value="3">
    <label class="radio average" for="3">3</label>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <div class="container_numbers">
   <input type="radio" id="4" name="question_1" class="required media_1" value="4">
    <label class="radio very_good" for="4">4</label>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

If I put a constant it is represented instead the variables average_1 and average_2 are not represented, how can I save the variables and take them out of the loop?

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    $(".media_1").click(function(event) {
        var total = 0;
        var media_1 = 0;
        $(".media_1:checked").each(function() {
            total += parseInt($(this).val());
            media_1 = total / 15;
        });
    
        if (total == 0) {
            $('#media_1').val('');
        } else {                
            $('#media_1').val(media_1);
        }

     $(".media_2").click(function(event) {
        var total = 0;
        var media_2 = 0;
      $(".media_2:checked").each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
        media_2 = total / 15;
      });
      
      if (total == 0) {
        $('#media_2').val('');
      } else {              
        $('#media_2').val(media_2);
      }

        var options = {
            series: [{
            data: [media_1, media_2]
          }],
            chart: {
            height: 350,
            type: 'bar',
            events: {
              click: function(chart, w, e) {
              }
            }
          },
          colors: colors,
          plotOptions: {
            bar: {
              borderRadius: 6,
              columnWidth: '45%',
              distributed: true,
            }
          },
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
          },
          legend: {
            show: false
          },
          xaxis: {
            categories: [
              ['Proactivity', 'Self-Confidence'],
            ],
            labels: {
              style: {
                colors: colors,
                fontSize: '12px'
              }
            }
          }
          };
  
          var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart_1"), options);
          chart.render();
    });
```

Comment: why don't you declare media_1 and media_2 outside click function.

Comment: I put media_1 in the function but it doesn't export the value out of the loop

Answer (score -1):

you can declare global vars like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var media_1,media_2,media_3,media_4,media_5,media_6,media_7,media_8,....,media_75;
media_1=media_2=media_3=media_4=media_5=media_6=media_7=media_8=....media_75=0;
    

$(".media_1").click(function(event) {
    var total = 0;
    //var media_1 = 0;
    $(".media_1:checked").each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
        media_1 = total / 15;
    });

    if (total == 0) {
        $('#media_1').val('');
    } else {                
        $('#media_1').val(media_1);
    }
   });
$(".media_2").click(function(event) {
    var total = 0;
    //var media_2 = 0;
  $(".media_2:checked").each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val());
    media_2 = total / 15;
  });
  
  if (total == 0) {
    $('#media_2').val('');
  } else {              
    $('#media_2').val(media_2);
  }
});
...
....
.....

var options = {
        series: [{
        data: [media_1, media_2,media_3,media_4,......,media_75]
      }],
        chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'bar',
        events: {
          click: function(chart, w, e) {
          }
        }
      },
      colors: colors,
      plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          borderRadius: 6,
          columnWidth: '45%',
          distributed: true,
        }
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      legend: {
        show: false
      },
      xaxis: {
        categories: [
          ['Proactivity', 'Self-Confidence'],
        ],
        labels: {
          style: {
            colors: colors,
            fontSize: '12px'
          }
        }
      }
      };

      var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart_1"), options);
      chart.render();
});
```

here the global media_1,media_2 .... will get updated and you can use them in

```
data: [media_1, media_2,media_3,media_4,......]
```

Comment: Didnt understand the reason for down vote...
Was this a wrong way of just somebody didnt like my answer because he himself was going to answer this...

Comment: Thanks, I tried with this method only that the value of average_1 remains 0 does not change

Comment: have you tried the second kind of variable declaration?, the one I commented 
i.e. 
`var media_1,media_2,media_3,media_4,media_5,media_6,media_7,media_8,....,media_75;
media_1=media_2=media_3=media_4=media_5=media_6=media_7=media_8=....media_75=0;`

Comment: You first wrote average_1  and now media_1, Please make sure you are declaring the same name  vars that you are going to use in calculations below..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229085/discussion-between-m-shoaib-qureshi-and-daniele-mastroberti).